# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest in WebApi 2

Tags: javascript, ajax, multithreading, web-services, xmlhttprequest

I have a webApi 2 application. I used `Ajax` several time in this way `async:false` , because sometimes

> The statement I am calling has to be complete before the next statement in my  function can be called

I get a browser warning then

**Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.**

I understand that calling a web service synchronisly can make problems such as a long waiting, browser crush ... etc. But I need to get the result before continuing the next statement.

I need to know

1. How can I avoid this warning and amke the call asynchrous?
2. Why `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated`? what is the meaning of this statement?

Comment: You could move your sync call to a web worker

Comment: or else, use `async` library to make your code flow as you wish. For example, you could use `async.series([yourAsnycFunctionOne, yourAsnycFunctionTwo, yourAsnycFunctionThree], finalFunctionToCall)`, so `yourAsnycFunctionOne, yourAsnycFunctionTwo, yourAsnycFunctionThree` will be called in series and `finalFunctionToCall` will be called in the end of the series.

Comment: https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback

Comment: @xyz : thank you for your comment, but in my case I think your solution don't work : I have for example a grid of customers and a form for adding new one and I change the visibility of tag each time. So when I click to add button the grid will be hidden and the form appears and when I submited the form I have to get the new full customers list before hidding the form and display the grid. I wish that my example were clear

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move your sync call to a web worker. But again, you will make it `async`.

Its better to make the current sync call to server as async call.

Example(pseudo sync call code):

```
var dataFromServer = makeSyncCallToServer();
//use dataFromServer
```

Example(pseudo async call code):

```
makeAsyncCallToServer(function(dataFromServer) {
  //use dataFromServer here
});
```

If you want to make multiple calls to server, then [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) comes handy here.

For example, you could use [async.series](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback)

```
async.series([yourAsnycFunctionOne, yourAsnycFunctionTwo, yourAsnycFunctionThree], finalFunctionToCall)
```

So `yourAsnycFunctionOne, yourAsnycFunctionTwo, yourAsnycFunctionThree` will be called in series and `finalFunctionToCall` will be called in the end of the series.

In your case, you could do something like:

```
function getCustomerList(callback) {
   //make the async http call and call "callback" with the customer data
}
function postFormDataToServer(formdata, callback) {
  //send form data server and call "callback" after successful post
}
function hideGrid() {}
function hideForm() {}
function showForm() {}
function showGrid() {}
$('#add-button').on('click', function() {
  showForm();
  hideGrid();
});
$('#form-id').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formdata = {/**populate form data**/};
  hideForm();
  postFormDataToServer(formdata, function() {
    getCustomerList(function(customerList) {
      //populate grid with new data
      showGrid();
    });
  });
});
```